# ALAssetsLibrary error - "Too many contexts. No space in contextList."

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt, alassetslibrary

I've received a couple of crash reports from users. I don't even know where to begin on this one. I am showing images from the asset library in a table view starting with a list of groups. I load the groups with the following code (on the main thread):

```
- (ALAssetsLibrary *)library {
    if (!_library) {
        _library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    }

    return _library;
}

- (void)determineGroups {
    ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [self library];
    [lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos | ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream | ALAssetsGroupFaces | ALAssetsGroupLibrary | ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupEvent usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (group) {
            if (!_groups) {
                _groups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }

            if ([group numberOfAssets]) {
                [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
                if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyType] isEqual:@(ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos)]) {
                    [_groups insertObject:group atIndex:0];
                } else {
                    [_groups addObject:group];
                }
            }
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // denied
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }];
}
```

When populating the table view I want to show the number of photos in each group. I do this by calling the "numberOfAssets" method on the group.

This all works just fine most of the time but crashes on rare occasions. Here is one of the stack traces with the relevant info (thread 5 crashed while the main thread was busy getting the number of assets in the group):

```
Crashed Thread:  5

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Too many contexts. No space in contextList.'

Thread 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x313a1c42 _CFStringGetLength2 + 26
1   CoreFoundation                      0x313aba41 -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKey:] + 133
2   CoreData                            0x312b5d2f -[NSSQLOrderIntermediate generateSQLStringInContext:] + 1283
3   CoreData                            0x312018f7 -[NSSQLFetchIntermediate generateSQLStringInContext:] + 515
4   CoreData                            0x311fe625 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 425
5   CoreData                            0x311fe3ad -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 509
6   CoreData                            0x311fdfc5 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 117
7   CoreData                            0x311fd73f -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 683
8   CoreData                            0x311fd205 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 469
9   CoreData                            0x311fc61d -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 1645
10  CoreData                            0x311faf17 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 647
11  PhotoLibraryServices                0x366cd4e5 -[PLManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 49
12  CoreData                            0x3121ad07 _faultBatchAtIndex + 623
13  CoreData                            0x3121aa53 -[_PFBatchFaultingArray getObjects:range:] + 143
14  CoreData                            0x3121a9c1 -[_PFBatchFaultingArray getObjects:] + 41
15  Foundation                          0x31cfbbe1 _filterObjectsUsingPredicate + 325
16  Foundation                          0x31d01b8d -[NSArray(NSPredicateSupport) filteredArrayUsingPredicate:] + 273
17  PhotoLibraryServices                0x366d86ad +[PLFilteredAlbum filteredIndexesInAlbum:predicate:] + 265
18  PhotoLibraryServices                0x366d8bd1 -[PLFilteredAlbum filteredIndexes] + 117
19  PhotoLibraryServices                0x366d8d75 -[PLFilteredAlbum countOfFilteredAssets] + 21
20  AssetsLibrary                       0x30ce25d5 __31-[ALAssetsGroup numberOfAssets]_block_invoke_0 + 41
21  CoreData                            0x31257fd1 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 89
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3971d4b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x397219f7 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 31
24  CoreData                            0x31258153 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 175
25  AssetsLibrary                       0x30ce414f -[ALAssetsLibrary _performBlockAndWait:] + 135
26  AssetsLibrary                       0x30ce8f59 -[ALAssetsGroupPrivate _performBlockAndWait:] + 177
27  AssetsLibrary                       0x30ce254b -[ALAssetsGroup numberOfAssets] + 259

Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x39804350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x397b7973 abort + 95
2   MyApp                               0x0074685f ___lldb_unnamed_function30167$$MyApp + 27
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3145b57f __handleUncaughtException + 615
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39306a65 _objc_terminate() + 129
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x38d5307b safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x38d53114 std::terminate() + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x38d54513 __cxa_throw + 123
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x393069bf objc_exception_throw + 95
9   CoreFoundation                      0x3145b15d +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
10  Foundation                          0x31d30b13 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 87
11  PhotoLibraryServices                0x366d0afb __addContextToList_block_invoke_0 + 179
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3971e11f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x39721ecf _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 143
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x39721dc1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 41
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3972291d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 185
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x39722ac1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 85
17  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x39752a11 _pthread_wqthread + 361
```

The crash was from an iPad running iOS 6.1.3. The app was built with a Base SDK of iOS 7 GM. The app uses ARC.

Is there something i should be doing different in my code to get the groups?

Answer (score 3):

- Definitely it is iOS issue and is reproduced when `enumerateGroupsWithTypes`:... method contains `ALAssetsGroupLibrary` inside types enumeration.
- You must use either `ALAssetsGroupALL` (that does not include `ALAssetsGroupLibrary`)
- or you may enumerate types with OR but don't include `ALAssetsGroupLibrary` to enumeration.
- I don't know what to do if you really need `ALAssetGroupLibrary` in types enumeration.
- My code is very similar to yours; if you want to reproduce this issue try to call determineGroups method many times (my issue reproduces when I do this 11 times exactly) but library object must be recreated each time you call this method (f.e. You may remove library at the end of `determineGroups` method.
- Or you may call **determineGroups** method each time for new receiver.). Also to reproduce this issue don't call determineGroups method inside single run loop
- it would be better if you create button and tap on this button would create new receiver and calls determineGroups for it. Now try to tap on this button many times.

Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by creating a sigleton object when using the ALAssetsLibrary.

```
+ (instancetype)defaultAssetsLibrary
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            defaultAssetsLibrary = [[self alloc] init];
        });
    }
    return defaultAssetsLibrary;
}
```